# Arel::Nodes::Intersect dynamic query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

How to build a query that intersects two or more queries dynamically?

```
arel = Arel::Nodes::Intersect.new(
 Language.where(foreign_key: 1),
 Language.where(foreign_key: 2),
 ...
)
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
keys = [1,2,3]
arel = Arel::Nodes::Intersect.new(
 keys.each do |key|
   Language.where(foreign_key: key)
 end
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Arel::Nodes::Intersect` object takes 2 arguments during initialization (the first query and the second query to intersect with the first). When you have more than 2 queries you wish to intersect the simplest way to deal with this is to use `Enumerable#reduce` to chain these intersections together. (`Arel::SelectManager` also provides a convenience method called `#intersect` where the receiver will be used as the first argument to `Arel::Nodes::Intersect`)

Example:

```
keys = [1,2,3]
scopes = keys.map {|k| Language.where(foreign_key: k).arel }

subquery = scopes.reduce do |memo,scope| 
    # Arel::Nodes::Intersect.new(memo,scope)
    memo.intersect(scope)
end 

Language.from(Arel::Nodes::As.new(subquery,Arel.sql(Language.arel_table.name)))
```